# How can I change a value in a field that sources another field in NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am currently migrating from vb to netsuite but I am not that familiar with netsuite. I am trying to get a field to generate a value based on other fields in a custom record form that I created. What I know as of now is how to upload scripts to netsuite but I am not sure how to use them properly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean field sourcing ? You want to source a field based on some other field value . Correct me if my understanding is incorrect to your context.

Comment: Yes, I want to set the value of a field based on other field values as the user enters them. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. :)

Comment: Did you check on help section of the NS for Setting Sourcing Criteria ?

Comment: yup I checked, I was just confused on where to set the field names on the script. I already got it.

Comment: I already found out how to do it. I just didnt know anything about NetSuite and the information that I was given was too many to process in a short period of time. Thanks for your time btw.